# mvc site, most secure way to preserve login credentials

Tags: asp.net-mvc, permissions, security, security-roles

ok so, i have this dilemma on how i should save login credentials in mvc at the same time avoid as much hit on the database. i know i can easily use `Forms Authentication` to save a User instance but is it advisable?

At the moment the way I do it is I store the `User Id` in a `cookie` which i then would access everytime an Action gets called that would "require" a login access. Before the action gets accessed the User Id will be used to retrieve a "New" User instance. This will be the same on every Action, I don't store the User in the cookie as I feel like once the cookie is compromised everything about the User shall be available for the hacker (Userid, email, roles, etc)

So if i have a ton of actions that would require a login that will be difficult on my bandwidth. What do you think of the method I'm using? Should I change it to have all the User object be stored in the cookie with a short timeout? Any ideas are greatly appreciated.
thanks!!

Comment: Please take the time to format your question. Use paragraphs/line breaks and proper punctuation/sentence structure. 

I'm sure a lot of people with the answer to your question over looked it because they didn't want to spend the time to parse out the real question from what you have to say. The FAQs (http://stackoverflow.com/faq) is a great place to learn how to ask questions.

Comment: Look at the edit that `Jayantha` made; learn from them.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you are trying to address a bandwidth issue.  That alone would suggest that you shouldn't store more than you have to (ie: session id) in the cookie.

There are two major problems (among others) for using cookies.
1) They are sent up on every request
2) There is only limited amount of information you can store.

In general, trusting anything the user gives you (that includes encrypted cookies) is bad.

How many concurrent users do you foresee having on your website?  Keep in mind that the database will be able to cache certain calls.  Furthermore, if you are using a ORM like nhibernate, you will get 2nd level caching there.  If all else fails, could you use the in-memory session management?

The biggest problem I have with putting userid's in the cookie is the entropy of that key.  Say your userId is an email.  All I have to do as an attacker is guess a userid that is valid in your system, and I will "automatically" become that user.  The reason why people use sessionID's and then retrieve the user is that in theory sessionID's are harder to guess.

My suggestion would be to use database session management if you are in a load balanced situation.  If not, use in-memory.  It is fast.  Memory is cheap.  And unless you are storing 10's of mb of data in session for each user, and you have 10000's of users, you should be fine.

As Ken stated, you should probably be using the standard [authorize] tags available with MVC as opposed to creating your own method.

Comment: well, the userid that i store are numbers, which i will use to query the emails and role credentials.in the beginning i would expect probably around 50 - 100 concurrent users. i don't think it'll reach 10 MBs tho, so you think I'll be fine with the current state of it right now? hitting the db everytime i access an action? pls see below Ken's reply for my comment regarding my setup.. thanks much!

Comment: @gdubs If all you are storing are the users's emails and roles, you are perfectly fine with in memory implementation.  What you are kinda doing here is premature optimization.  Get an implementation up and then load test it to see how it performs.  If it doesn't meet your criteria (say page load time less than 5 sec) then switch it around to see if you can get an implementation to do that....

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you pretty much implemented form based authentication and something comparable to the [Authorize] attribute.

> So if i have a ton of actions that would require a login that will be difficult on my bandwidth

Forms Authentication uses a cookie and is baked into the system. If you don't want to store your user information in SQLServer there are plenty of other options.

It sounds like you are trying to implement something that is already done. In my opinion, let's leave the security stuff to people that know about security. I would suggest working within the framework provided unless you have **proof** that you solution needs something else!

Comment: i actually am using the normal [authorize] tag, i just added an actionfilter to override onactionexecuting. i am already using formsauthentication too, but i was only storing userids, and not the whole user details, which means i still need to query the database for the users Role credentials everytime it tries to access an action. even if i take out the actionfilter,since my security is role based, unless i will store the roles in the cookie then i have to hit the db still.. unless there's a secure way of caching it..

Answer (score 0):

There is a **UserData** property on the **FormsAuthenticationTicket** object that could be used to store additional data other than the Username.

I had a project that had a similar need. I stored the values as a *NameValueCollection* encoded like a query string:

```
 "email=myemail@some.com&roles=Somebody&roles=Special"
```

(there's also a handy HttpUtility.ParseQueryString() method that is useful for getting the values back out of the UserData property)

You can use the **FormsAuthentication.Encrypt** and **FormsAuthentication.Decrypt** to convert the ticket to and from the Cookie value.

Comment: interesting... ill look into that. but isn't formsauthentication automatically encrypts the data? was wondering if i store the user context directly instead of creating that string ?